# How do I make a nav bar with a gradient background?

Tags: html, css, background, gradient, nav

I am trying to make the background a linear gradient. I have tried

```
nav {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, gray, black); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(black, gray, black); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, gray, black); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(black, gray, black); /* Standard syntax */
  }
```

but it looks very choppy... Does anyone know any fixes to that off the top of their head? No need to go out of the way to look it up, though!

Comment: I don't get it, how do you want the `linear-gradient` to be?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I want it to be my navagation bar background. I made it, it just looks choppy.

Comment: I don't think there exist any CSS fix for this problem.

Comment: @Tristen care to create a jsfiddle to show us what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @KyleT Ok. I have no idea what that is, but I am looking at it.

Comment: @Tristen i have created a crude one for you using the css you provided here http://jsfiddle.net/6rhdhsty/ is this not what you wanted? have you tried a css gradient generator to get it just the way you want? i have used this one before to great effect http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ ive even copied your current css into it as a starting point.

Comment: Take a screenshot of your problem - "but it looks very choppy..." doesn't help us.

Comment: @KyleT [link](http://jsfiddle.net/h2syntgb/)

Comment: @Tristen what do you mean choppy though? is there a certain direction you want the gradient to be aligned?

Comment: @KyleT No it just did not look like it blended well. I used colorzilla and got a great gradient! [Check it out here!](http://jsfiddle.net/h2syntgb/1/
)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of KyleT, I was able to use colorzilla.com in order to get code for a premade gradient, which is the website I recommend for anyone with the same question! Also, I used jsfiddle.com to test the gradient, and now I know about the basics of stackoverflow.com!

Comment: @Tristen ^^ That is an automatic comment generated by the review queue. I was one of what will be several reviewers of your answer for moderation due to its content. I didn't manually type it - that's just what comes out.

Comment: @Tristen If you edit to expand this into a more complete answer that directly addresses the original question with a solution, it will probably survive the review queue.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Is this a complete answer? Also, I said thanks to recognize the person who helped me.

Comment: @Tristen If there is any relevant code to add, you should add it, or an explanation of why it was choppy-looking originally and what difference colorzilla made. Otherwise, be sure to return to this answer after the time period expires for self-answering (many 8hrs, I can't remember?) and mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark